# Issue with CSS on Home Page

Tags: theming

I have a vexing issue. I'm using the equal heights module to ensure two blocks are of equal height on the home page of my site. Inside each block, at the bottom of each block, is a read more link. I need the read more links to be spaced so that they are both at the bottom of each block, positioned identically on the page (within their respective blocks). When I'm logged in to the site as an ADMIN the CSS I'm using is working fine (see first screenshot below for the orange read more links showing on each side). However, when I log OUT of the site (or login as another user) and view the home page the 'read more' links are collapsing together at the top of the page in the middle for some reason (see the second screenshot). They are using the exact same CSS so I don't know why it's doing this.

Note: I tried giving another user all the same permissions as the admin to see if that fixed it and it did NOT fix the problem, so I don't think it's a permissions issue.

[image: Logged in - works great!]
[image: Not logged in - collapsing at the top for some reason]

Ok, so here's the CSS (for one of the blocks - they are the same) I'm using to position the elements:

```
#block-views-featured-resource-block .views-field-view-node {
position: absolute;
margin-bottom: 8px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
text-align: center;
left: 20%;
width: 50%;
bottom: 0;
@media screen and (max-width: 959px) {
    position: absolute;
}
}
```

And here's the page--front.tpl.php file:

```
<div id="page">
```

```
<?php if ($logo): ?>
    <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); 
?>" rel="home" id="logo">
    <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" /> 
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($page['top_navigation']); ?>
<?php print render($page['user_menu']); ?>
```

```
<div id="content" class="column" role="main">

  <?php /** print $breadcrumb; */ ?>

  <a id="main-content"></a>

  <?php print render($page['pathfinder_header']); ?>
  <?php print render($page['introduction']); ?>
  <?php print render($tabs); ?>
  <?php print render($page['help']); ?>

  <?php if ($action_links): ?>
    <ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="feat-container">
  <?php print render($page['featured_resource']); ?>
  <?php print render($page['hp_video']); ?>
  <?php print render($page['whats_new']); ?>      
  </div>

  <?php print render($page['find_your_path']); ?>
  <?php print render($page['search_library']); ?>
  <?php print render($page['browse_library']); ?>

  <?php print render($page['content']); ?>

  <?php print $feed_icons; ?>
</div>
```

The items in question are within the 'feat-container'  in the page.tpl above.

Anyone have ideas why when I'm logged in as an admin user they work but not for any other user? It makes no sense to me. I tried clearing the cache...that didn't help. I flushed with drush. That didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the equalheights module, perhaps it maybe causing this issue? You don't need a module to give blocks equal heights, when you can easily do that with css.

I noticed on the top screenshot there is no video, while the bottom has a video.

Anyhow, based on your screenshot, it seems that you can fix this by adding a `position: relative;` to the div id or class that is wrapping the blocks. Which would be #block-views-featured-resource-block and what ever the name the Grand station Resource block id is.

Comment: thanks! It was the position:relative bit. So I removed the <div> feat-resource from the grouping in the tpl and just added position relative to the containing blocks. The equalheights module is being used because those blocks change in height every week and not evenly. Thanks again!